# Eventbrite call individual tags

Tags: api, tags, eventbrite

I am looking at pulling data from the Eventbrite api individually, as it stands I have the following which pulls the event details using eventListRow function.

```
$eb_client = new Eventbrite( array('app_key'=> $row['app_key'],
                               'user_key'=> $row['user_key']));                              
 }

 $event = $eb_client->event_get( array('id' => '$row[event_id']') );
 print( Eventbrite::eventListRow($event->event) );
```

I have connected to the api and can pull the data using the selected functions from eventbrite.php.

Could anyone point me in the right direction to pull the data within each function individually, eg.eventListRow to create individual tags. For example just pull the .$evnt->title.

Any assistance appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Many thanks
Ben

Answer (score 0):

eventListRow is a sample function that is meant to show you how to convert an event object into a string of HTML.  You can read the source here:
https://github.com/ryanjarvinen/eventbrite.php/blob/master/Eventbrite.php#L249

I'd remove that line from your code, or replace it with another function that you've defined:

```
print($event->event->title);
```

Once you get an event object back from the API, you should be able to access it's attributes, which are outlined here: http://developer.eventbrite.com/doc/events/

In PHP, `var_dump($evnt);` can be useful way to inspect your API response objects.

Comment: Thanks for that, works a treat. I have set up template tags for each event attribute and all works well. Can I check if the attribute exists? For example 'event_logo_ssl'      =>  ($event->event->logo_sll), is there a way for me to check if this exists before calling it?

Comment: As at the moment i get php error Message: Undefined property: stdClass::$logo_sll if this doesn't exist.

Comment: The eventListRow function shows how to check to see if the optional venue object is available. https://github.com/ryanjarvinen/eventbrite.php/blob/master/Eventbrite.php#L249